# Performance Issue due to Network

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, networking, large-data

I am currently working on a .NET (3.5) page that has a large dataset and performance is a main concern for the users sitting in 2 different locations (separated 12 hours apart).

Goal & Requirements:

1. I have a result set of approximately 2500 records x 30 columns.
2. Display as a Tabular view with client side sorting and plenty of cell formatting.
3. Load time reasonably fast in two different locations separated 12 hours apart (one sits next to the web browser and the other sits half way across the globe from the web server).

I have tried 2 different approach but could not satisfy both users. Here's what I've tried so far:

- Client Side Grid

  - Pros:
  - Smaller data packets sent through the wire; The web server is sending < 1 MB. Faster through the network
  - Cons:
  - Javascript/JQuery process to generate the grid takes a good 10 - 15 seconds (varies).

Summary: Client Side Grid is beneficial for the users sitting a **distance** away from the web server. However, not so much for the user sitting next to the server. Now the user sitting next to the server will have to sit and wait for the JQuery/Javascript to build the table.

- Server Side Grid

  - Pros:
  - Faster Rendering as most if not all mark up is completed on web server (Server Side).
  - Cons:
  - Large data packets sent through the wire; The web server is sending 3.5 - 5 MB. Much slower through the network. (It takes approximately 30+ seconds to retrieve the page of 3.7 MB)

Summary: Server Side Grid is beneficial for the users sitting **next** to the web server (as it loads almost instantaneous - barely 1 second for 3 MB). Likewise, for the user sitting on the other side of the globe suffers from the network transfer - 30+ seconds for 3.MB page.

After googling and experimenting; I am left still scratching my head on how to make both of these users happy.

*Note: I've decided not to include any source code as it would not assist you in any way possible.

I know that there's no one size fits all solution but I am looking for something that hits at least middle ground to satisfy both of these users.

Generally, at the very least, I would like to give the users the impression that the page is 'loaded'(fast) - start rendering before all data arrives; although it may still be loading data. I.e. Infinite Scrolling perhaps.

I am looking for a creative ideas; hence if your suggestion includes moving the server half-way across the globe; increase your bandwidth or any other far-fetched ideas; I would appreciate it if you keep your ideas to yourself.

Thanks.

D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use [server side paging](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506081930/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/041206-1.shtml) on your grid & just load 10 entries
   per page
2. You can provide a 'download as pdf' file option if users want
   to view the whole grid

You can further use client side grid with server side paging to improve access time. I think gridview with server side paging would do just fine. If you need to display all records at once then it is a separate problem.

Comment: We've explore the idea of using server-side paging; our concern is the performance of sorting (multi-sorting). I have built one with DataTables (datatables.net - Client Side Grid) and performance is great for machine far away. [Network Transfer for JSON data + javascript to build the grid from scratch is much faster than the network latency of sending a completed server side grid to client machine on other side of the globe; unfortunately the local users don't have network latency and the javascript processing is added overhead]. Preferably, display all records; paging is last option. Thanks

Comment: Server Side Paging it is. It my last and final option.

Comment: @SolidSnake you can use progress indicators to further facilitate the users.

Answer (score 2):

Server side paging?

You said *Creative ideas*, so have you got gzip switched on to compress the data you are sending? Also, try minifying the html?

Comment: I have considered server side paging; however I forgot to mention that one of the required functionality (multi-column sorting). Theoretically, this could potentially cause performance issue. As each sort will invoke a postback; sort the entire data by column 1 then sort by column 2. The number of records also varies and likely to grow by another 1,000. We are currently using a WAN Scaler to compress the data transfer between the two points. I'll explore and test the paging solution and see hows the performance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used the [DHTMLX Grid](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/index.shtml) for this use. It has both the ability to infinite scroll and also paging. Only requesting data for that shown on the page / visible scroll area (reducing the amount of data sent over the wire at any given time. It's also pretty customisable and has many other features that you may find useful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My grid will need to display 29 columns and almost each column will have some form of formatting (background color, text color, hyperlink, etc). Hence, before I try it out; could I ask how long does DHTMLX Grid takes to render once it receives the data. I am currently using DataTables(datatable.net) and it takes almost a good 6 - 15 seconds to render depending on the size of the data. I have also implemented the 'defer-render option' as well where only rows visible on screen is rendered. For DataTables, it is the initial rendering that is causing the problem.

Comment: From our experience the grid renders in less than a second. We regularly have > 20 columns. We utilise both the infinite scroll and paging, so the amount of the grid that needs to be rendered isn't that great. Most of the data-sets being displayed are greater than a 1000 rows (Up to 10,000, although what you would do with that amount data is questionable). If you are only loading a sub-set of data initially, why is the rendering taking so long?

Comment: I am not sure whether this is an issue with DataTables plugin (as a whole) or the problem lies with the way it was used. I am not using paging at all with DataTables (but using DeferRender ~ which renders the row only when it comes into view). I have proposed to use Server Side Paging as a final and only solution to address this performance issue. Paging seems to alleviate the performance issue to an acceptable time range for both locations (and probably the only viable option left). Thanks for the suggestions though.